# Question about Symmetry of second derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was learning about the Symmetry of second derivatives that states:

Let $f:U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow R$ and let the partial derivatives
$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y } $ and $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y \partial x } $ of a function f(x,y) be existing and continuous in a $\epsilon$ neighborhood of a specific point (a,b), this implies that
$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y } =\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y \partial x }$

My Question now is , if $f:U \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow R$ and if the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x \partial y } $, $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial y \partial x } $ exist and are continuous (in x and y) in a $\epsilon$ neighborhood of (a,b,c) does
equality still hold? Or do I need continuity in (x,y,z) for the equality?

Comment: The equality still holds for those $z$ satisfying the hypothesis in $(x,y)$ for you can apply the result to the partial functions $(x,y) \mapsto f_z(x,y) := f(x,y,z).$ __Also__, the following result is true: if $f$ is a multivariable function that is twice differentiable (without assumptions on the continuity of the second derivative), then the second derivative of $f$ is symmetric, in particular, $\partial_{ij} f = \partial_{ji} f$ for all indices $i,j.$